# facebook_ads_api show"nw_socket_set_common_sockopts setsockopt SO_NOAPNFALLBK failed: [42] Protocol not available, dumping backtrace"

Tags: ios, xcode8, facebook-ads-api

i m using Facebook Audience Network SDK,
this is my code:

```
-(void)loadInterstitialAd
{
    FBInterstitialAd *interstitialAd =
    [[FBInterstitialAd alloc] initWithPlacementID:@"1783280735273073_1783280748606405"];
    interstitialAd.delegate = self;
    [interstitialAd loadAd];
}
```

but there is a problem:

```
2016-10-10 15:44:47.296707 facebookADTest[35670:2286565] [] nw_socket_set_common_sockopts setsockopt SO_NOAPNFALLBK failed: [42] Protocol not available, dumping backtrace:
    [x86_64] libnetcore-856.1.8
0   libsystem_network.dylib             0x00000001064af80e __nw_create_backtrace_string + 123
1   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010693f194 nw_socket_add_input_handler + 3002
2   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010691cdb8 nw_endpoint_flow_attach_protocols + 3768
3   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010691bdd5 nw_endpoint_flow_setup_socket + 563
4   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010691ab34 -[NWConcrete_nw_endpoint_flow startWithHandler:] + 2612
5   libnetwork.dylib                    0x0000000106935d11 nw_endpoint_handler_path_change + 1261
6   libnetwork.dylib                    0x0000000106935740 nw_endpoint_handler_start + 570
7   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010694d003 nw_endpoint_resolver_start_next_child + 2240
8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000
```

i dont know what case this problem,and i cannot find any info about it,is there any idea?

Comment: i dont think the protocol will case this problem because my code is same as the facebook's example code;

Answer (score 1):

I ensure you are using `simulator` test,`SO_NOAPNFALLBK` socket is `Apple` add in `iOS10`, it use in real device.

You could close it in the `Scheme`:

`Edit Scheme` -> `Arguments` -> `Environment Variables` -> add `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE:disable`

Hope this can solve your problem.

Comment: ty very much~~~

Comment: Could you please explain what this is a little more? I don't want to turn off something if it is telling me about a real issue.